# AngularJS - Filtering when targeting another page

Tags: angularjs

I have built a simple filter with angularJS, the html is like

```
<a class="filterbutton" ng-click="filters.grade = '7'">7 Grade</a>
<a class="filterbutton" ng-click="filters.grade = '6'">6 Grade</a>
<a class="filterbutton" ng-click="filters.grade = ''">X Clear Filters</a>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:filters">{{name.student}}, {{name.grade}} grade</li>
</ul>
```

And the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.filters = { };

$scope.names = [{
"student": "Jimmy", "grade":7
}, {
"student": "Johny", "grade":7
}, {
"student": "Little Joe", "grade":6
}];
});
```

This works as expected. But what I wanted to do is to be able to check one of the filters and jump to another page with the same controller, so that when loaded the second page would be already filtered. So for example, if I click "filter by 7 grade in another page", it would jump to anotherpage.html and the output there would be already filtered.

I have [made a plunkr here](http://plnkr.co/edit/g3LTazjI4nlhLL5FW2H5?p=preview) to illustrate what I mean. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should use routing with `ng-view` directive and then at controller get route value parameter i.e. selected filter and assign it to `$scope.filters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can try this simple [solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/Uu9bZSUCOXfz7p6mqxBf?p=preview):

**HTML** (add filter parameter to *href* attribute):

```
<a class="filterbutton" href="anotherpage.html?filter=7">Filter by 7 Grade in Another Page</a>
<a class="filterbutton" href="anotherpage.html?filter=6">Filter by 6 Grade in Another Page</a>
```

**Javascript** (get them from url and apply it)

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.filters = { grade : window.location.search.replace('?filter=','') };

  $scope.names = [{
    "student": "Jimmy", "grade":7
  }, {
    "student": "Johny", "grade":7
  }, {
    "student": "Little Joe", "grade":6
  }];

});
```

Comment: Brilliant, that was exactly I was looking for (as I wanted to have two separated pages). Thanks!